# Entity Reference Roles

Tags: nodes, entities

I've created a **Entity Reference** from **customer** to **contract** and I created a user which can create a **customer**.

Now is the problem that I can't select any **contract** with the new user when I try to create a new **customer**.

The only solution I found is to give the new user the **Bypass content access control** permissions. But then he also can create a **contract**. And I don't want that user to do that.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you must not have given that specific user/role, the permission to "View Published Content". Verify that please.

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast response! Sorry for my late response. And It is given. http://i.imgur.com/HC3R2hC.png

Comment: it is possible .. that another module .. may be creating issues..?? have u installed "node access" type module which controls permissions

Comment: I only installed & enabled extra:
* Chaos tools
* Date
* Date API
* Entity Reference
* Serial
* Entity API
* Universally Unique ID